# Shouldn't there be a prompt for when I can post my next question?

Tags: discussion, questions, rate-limiting

It is quite frustrating to see the message "You can only post once every 90 minutes.". Atleast there should be a message to let us know when we can post our next question.

Comment: The vast majority of users never hit these rate limits, so the DB queries can be optimized by not requesting that information until it is actually necessary.

Comment: It's difficult to come up with any scenario that would require such a question frequency:(

Comment: @yivi New users with less than 125 reputation can only ask one question every 90 minutes.

Comment: @gparyani So? What’s your point exactly?

Comment: @yivi So it's not exactly the case that "the vast majority of users never hit these rate limits".

Comment: @gparyani I still maintain that statement is true.

Comment: @gparyani Asking a new question every 90 minutes is hardly enough time for proper research. It's reasonable to prefer not to modify or add complexity to the database queries just to improve the UX of this particular user group.

Answer (score 15):

It's something we expect users to be able to keep track of. It's a minimal benchmark to be able to check the time and how much is remaining to be able to work out when you can post your next question.

There comes a point on the site where each user needs to hold a certain level of self-responsibility. It is a programming website afterall and expecting people to be able to add 90 minutes to their current time to work out what that time would be is not too much to ask.